# Php regular expression not replacing text

Tags: php

Regular expression is not replacing the content.

```
$post_content = '<p>M-Kavach is a mobile device security solution which focuses on various threats related to android mobile device. It is an initiative by indian government . As you all know the Modi government took the decision to demonetize Rs 500 and Rs 1000 notes. And a digital india campaign has been started on a very vast scale. So india is going digital. There are also threats to it . More hackers and cyber criminals would evolve. So to save Indian government has taken an initiative Cyber Swachhta Kendra (botnet cleaning and malware analysis centre). Indian government has spent Rs 90 crores on Cyber Swachhta Kendra taking care of digital india. Currently we have so called antivirus software only for android device but keep visiting this site because soon we are going to post PC antivirus software by indian government.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;</p>
<p><img src="source/pankaj260/codexworld.png?1514909769678" alt="codexworld" width="502" height="477" /></p>
<p>Features of Mkavach are :&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;<br />Restricted access to critical applications&lt;br&gt;<br />Hardware resource control in terms of access to WiFi, Bluetooth, Camera and MobileData&lt;br&gt;<br />Intimates unauthorized SIM changes to trusted mobile number through SMS&lt;br&gt;<br />Remote wipe of Contacts &amp; Call-Logs using SMS&lt;br&gt;<br />Option to Factory Reset the device remotely using SMS&lt;br&gt;<br />Blocks unwanted Calls &amp; SMS&lt;br&gt;<br />Easy backup &amp; restore&lt;br&gt;<br />Protects against JavaScript Malware&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;<br />&lt;a 
<img src="source/pankaj260/codexworld.png?1514909769678" alt="codexworld" width="502" height="477" /></p>
href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cdac.mkavach" target="_blank"&gt;Download Mkavach&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;<br />&lt;b&gt; Do visit for pc anti virus by indian government&lt;b&gt;</p>';

preg_replace('(src="source\/)','(src="admin\/source\/)',$post_content);
```

Comment: Works fine, except why do you escape the `/`?  You have backslash ending up in your result. And `str_replace` is what to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new string is returned by preg_replace(), so you need to assign it to a variable:

```
$post_content = preg_replace('(src="source\/)','(src="admin\/source\/)',$post_content);
```

Answer (score 3):

since you are not needing the power of a regular expression to complete your replacement, consider using `str_ireplace()` instead.  Here is a link to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).

your code will be similar:

```
str_ireplace('src="source/','src="admin/source/)',$post_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape `/` on the second parameter otherwise you get this as result:

`source/` === replaced with ===> `admin\/source\/`

Finally you have to assign the result of `preg_replace` to a variable (or pass it to some function...)

```
$post_content = preg_replace('(src="source\/)','(src="admin/source/)',$post_content);
```

---

Note that to perform a simple find/replace on a string you may just use **[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/it/function.str-replace.php)**

```
$post_content = str_replace( 'src="source/', 'src="admin/source/)', $post_content );
```